# How do I calculate VWAP in Flux?

Tags: influxdb

I am piping a lot of stock data into InfluxDB. The schema is as follows:
tradeTime as the timestamp, tradeId and ticker are the tags, price (p) and volume (v) are the fields.

I am trying to calculate the VWAP for the last minute for every single trade. The formula is sum(p1*v1 + p2*v2 + p3*v3 + ...) / (v1+v2+v3+...).

I am trying to run following InfluxQL:

```
SELECT SUM(pv) / SUM(volume) AS VWAP FROM (
       SELECT price*volume AS pv, volume FROM trade
       WHERE time > NOW() - 1m) 
GROUP BY time(1m)
```

How could I incorporate with Moving Average function as I need to run this for every single trade?

Besides, I would like to translate this into Flux as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if Influxdb can do that for every trade, but I know Kinetica can.  Here's the code for VWAP.

```
SELECT ticker, SUM(price * volume) / SUM(volume) AS VWAP
FROM trade
WHERE TIMEBOUNDARYDIFF('MINUTE', tradeTime, NOW()) < 1
GROUP BY ticker
```

Comment: thx. That function looks great. However, it seems that Kinetica doesn't offer open-source version though ;(

Comment: The [developer edition](https://www.kinetica.com/developer_edition/) is totally free to use.  And there is a free [cloud version](https://cloud.kinetica.com/trynow/) as well.

Comment: cool. thx. Let me try with that then.